# Keycloak - What is the best way to add an endpoint that uses a different messaging protocol (ie not HTTP)?

Tags: keycloak

We are looking to use Keycloak as an identity management system. What is the best way to get Keycloak to use a custom messaging protocol (that is not HTTP)? I'm looking at the Keycloak Server Developer Guide section about [extending the server by adding a custom SPI](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/6.0/server_development/index.html#_extensions_spi). Is this the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  I would implement SPI and the corresponding ProviderFactory and Provider, as you've mentioned.

In the past, I wrote a Kafka listener that picks messages off of a topic using this SPI strategy, and it works quite nicely.  You'll need to do the following to get it to work:

1. Add your Spi class to `META-INF/services/org.keycloak.provider.Spi`
2. Create a file with the name of your `ProviderFactory` in `META-INF/services` and add your provider factory impl class there
3. Add the jar as a module in `modules/system/layers/keycloak/com/yourcompany/yourmodule/main
4. Add a `module.xml` config in the same directory as above.  You'll need to add dependencies as appropriate here.  Since you're implementing a custom protocol, you'll probably need to add a module containing that library and add it as a dependency.  For example, I had to add kafka-clients.jar as a separate module and then list it as a dependency in my custom provider.
5. Modify `standalone.xml` and/or `standalone-ha.xml` to add the provider (see the existing `<providers>` block under the keycloak-server subsystem).  Keycloak has some documentation on how to do this.